# Multer Muti Upload Image With Express

Tags: node.js, express

I use React and Express for create Mutiupload Image

multer.js

```
const multer = require('multer');

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, './public/')
    },
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, new Date().toISOString() + '-' + file.originalname)
    }
})


const fileFilter = (req, file, cb) => {
    if (file.mimetype === 'image/jpeg' || file.mimetype === 'image/png') {
        cb(null, true)
    } else {
        //reject file
        cb({message: 'Unsupported file format'}, false)
    }
}

const upload = multer({
    storage: storage,
    limits: { fileSize: 1024 * 1024 },
    fileFilter: fileFilter
})

module.exports = upload;
```

post.controller.js

```
 async onInsert(req, res) {
        try {

            let result = await Service.insert(req.body)
            res.success(result, 201);
        } catch (error) {
            res.error(error.message, error.status)
        }
    },
```

post.service.js

```
 insert(data) {
        return new Promise(async(resolve, reject) => {
            try {
                const obj = new Post(data)
                let inserted = await obj.save()
                resolve(inserted)
            } catch (error) {
                reject(methods.error(error.message, 400))
            }
        });
    },
```

I try to implements Multer on this controller but it can't upload anyway . so how to implements mutiple upload image with this code thank

I use mongoose by the way

Answer (score 0):

```
const fileStorage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, 'images');
  },
  filename: (req, file, cb) => {

    cb(null, new Date().toISOString().replace(/:/g, '-') + file.originalname);
  }
});

const fileFilter = (req, file, cb) => {
  if (
    file.mimetype === 'image/png' ||
    file.mimetype === 'image/jpg' ||
    file.mimetype === 'image/jpeg'
  ) {
    cb(null, true);
  } else {
    cb(null, false);
  }
};

const csrfProtection = csrf();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(
  multer({ storage: fileStorage, fileFilter: fileFilter }).fields(
    [
      
      { 
        name: 'image1', 
        maxCount: 1 
      }, 
      { 
        name: 'image', 
        maxCount: 1 
      }, 
      { 
        name: 'passbook', 
        maxCount: 1 
      },
      {
        name:'certificate',
        maxCount:1
      }
    ]
  )
);
```

**in controller**

```
const image=req.files.image1;
  const passbook=req.files.passbook;
  const certificate=req.files.passbook;

  if (!image || !passbook || !certificate) {
    console.log("img err");
    return res.redirect('admin/');
  }
  
  const imageUrl = image[0].path;
  const passbookUrl= passbook[0].path;
  const certificateUrl= certificate[0].path;
```

this works for me but i have only used Nodejs